# Building path independent mod_rewrite statements for generic .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have three small web applications stored under a shared web root:

- www.example.com/app1/
- www.example.com/app2/
- www.example.com/app3/
- www.example.com/app4/

each application has a `.htaccess` file containing some run-off-the-mill `mod_rewrite` statements to rewrite urls like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$
RewriteRule .* /app1/index.php?selectedProfile=%1&match=%2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

now, I would like to have a *generic* `.htaccess` file in each `/app{n}` directory. So, no `RewriteBase` and no `/app{n}` prefix in the RewriteConds.

One idea I had was making the first level a wildcard directory as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$
```

seeing as the `.htaccess` file gets triggered only when the `/app{n}` directory is entered, this should work.

Is this an acceptable solution?

Are there other, better ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to specify the full path. You can use relative paths that are then resolved from the base path.

So try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?selectedProfile=$1&match=$2 [QSA]
```

You could even use just this single rule in your document root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^(app\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ $1/index.php?selectedProfile=$2&match=$3 [QSA]
```